# $_REQUEST['oauth_verifier'] is empty

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter, oauth

I am using the Abraham Library with CodeIgniter and having this issue.

I know that twitter has changed something recently with their API, and I've tried to do the fix that was mentioned with:

```
$access_token = $connection->getAccessToken($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']);
```

But now my script tells me that `$_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']` is not set?

What is going on? My site worked fine 4 days ago?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having a similar issue, but with iOS, not PHP. Here are the details about exactly what was changed last week with Twitter's API.

https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/16443

In your context, you might want to check to make sure you're passing a valid callback url to obtain the oauth_verifier string.